# Is there a way to binding two values in label - xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a `listview` and want to bind two values from xaml. If it's possible can I get example how to do that ?

```
 <StackLayout Spacing="0" x:Name="ExchangeStack">
        <ListView x:Name="lstExchange" HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.View>
                            <Grid BackgroundColor="#454545">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="2"></RowDefinition>

                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Name}" XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" TextColor="#2196F3" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                                <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat='{0:F0} $'}" XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" TextColor="#2bff00" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                                <BoxView Color="White" HeightRequest="1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell.View>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
```

I want to bind `Name` and `Price` on one label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible

```
                            <Label.Text>
                                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
                                    <Binding Path="Name" />
                                    <Binding Path="Price" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Label.Text>
```

https://xamgirl.com/understanding-multi-binding-in-xamarin-forms/